# python package for parsing strings based on a grammar

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing, grammar

I have a command line tool which reads an in input string via

```
input = ...
```

Now, I want to check the input string for different cases (how many words, is the 2nd word a number, keywords, ...). Basically, I want to parse the string based on a regular grammar. I only have a handful of cases but it looks awful with all the if-statements. Also, match/case does not really help here as I want to check for conditions like if a word represents a number.

Is there any python package which implements a grammar parser?

Comment: You can't avoid programming in general. There're plenty of modules, most of cases you can cover using [built-in methods of `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and/or [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you have some specific task, you can ask about it, but current question is too broad to give precise answer. **P.S.** do not use `input` or name of any other name of built-in [class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types)/[function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a name of variable.

Comment: Unfortunately asking for libraries or other off site resources are explicitely off topic here, because they end in an unordered list of answers, each providing a library they used. But if you are used to lex and yacc parsing (BNF grammar), [PLY](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) is a Python port of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have this library, but you have to write your own grammar: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark

See the "Dragon book" for info about writting parsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [linguistic features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features.) of SpaCy. The [rules-based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) may also be useful. There is a [web-based demo](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher) so you can see if it is the kind of thing you are looking for.